# Emberjs - setProperties from a Promise

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to set a variable in my router from the inside of a promise, but it seems that it is not set properly.

I have create a small example to show you :

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    myVar: null,

    model: function() {
        var data = getData();
        console.log(myVar); // = null
        return data;
    },
    getData: function() {
        var self = this;
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
            self.setProperties({ myVar: 42 });

            resolve(someGoodStuff);

            reject(someBadStuff)
        });
    }
})
```

When I try to display myVar, it still at null even when it was waiting for the promise to resolve...
Do I need to do something special ? or I'm doing it wrongly ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gosoj/3/edit?html,css,js,output

I'm not entirely sure what you are going for here, so there is also some other commented code that may have been your intention.

I think maybe the problem was when you were console logging, as well as the fact that you weren't using your getters and setters properly, and the way you were calling `getData()`

Here is the code:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  myVar: null,

  model: function() {
    var data = this.getData();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(this.get('myVar')); // = null
    return data;
  },
  getData: function() {
    var self = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        self.setProperties({ myVar: 42 });
        resolve(42);

        reject(reason);
    }).then(function (value) {
        //self.setProperties({ myVar: value });
        console.log(self.get('myVar'));
    }, function(reason){
      console.log(reason);
    });
  }
})
```